# Required Body [file] not specified Micronaut Multipart upload

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-client, micronaut-rest

Trying to upload the file using declarative HTTP client as below

**Http CLient**

```
@Client("http://localhost:8080/product")
public interface IHttpClient {
    @Post(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public String post(@Body MultipartBody file);
}
```

Dependency injection to Client

```
@Controller("/productManager")
public class ProductManagerController implements IProductOperation{
    private final IHttpClient iProduct;

    public ProductManagerController(IHttpClient iProduct) {
        this.iProduct = iProduct;
    }

    @Override
    public String post(CompletedFileUpload file) throws IOException {
        MultipartBody requestBody = MultipartBody.builder().addPart("file", file.getFilename(), MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE, file.getBytes()).build();
        return this.iProduct.post(requestBody);
    }
}
```

**Product controller**

```
@Controller("/product")
public class ProductController implements IProductOperation {
    @Post(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public String post(@Body MultipartBody file)  {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**CURL**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/productManager' \
--form 'file=@"/Users/macbook/Downloads/anand 001.jpg"'
```

An exception I am facing

```
02:32:24.519 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 7442ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8080
02:32:33.985 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] DEBUG i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Sending HTTP POST to http://localhost:8080/product
02:32:33.990 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Accept: multipart/form-data
02:32:33.993 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=ac4442578cac3c2
02:32:33.994 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - transfer-encoding: chunked
02:32:33.994 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - host: localhost:8080
02:32:33.995 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - connection: close
02:32:35.260 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] DEBUG i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Received response 400 from http://localhost:8080/product
02:32:35.260 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Content-Type: application/json
02:32:35.260 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - content-length: 119
02:32:35.260 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - connection: close
02:32:35.260 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - Response Body
02:32:35.261 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - ----
02:32:35.261 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - {"message":"Required Body [file] not specified","path":"/file","_links":{"self":{"href":"/product","templated":false}}}
02:32:35.261 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-4] TRACE i.m.h.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient - ----
02:32:35.364 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] ERROR i.m.r.intercept.RecoveryInterceptor - Type [com.example.IProduct$Intercepted] executed with error: Required Body [file] not specified
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Required Body [file] not specified
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$12.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:2140)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.netty.DefaultHttpClient$12.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:2055)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:193)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsClientHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsClientHandler.java:183)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be more than one issue within your implementation, and here down the details.

#### Client and Server MultipartBody

The post misses the most important part to diagnose the error, which is class `import`s.

When programmatically building *multipart* requests, *Micronaut* affords the `io.micronaut.http.client.multipart.MultipartBody` type to build *multipart/form-data* requests.
Note the FQN (Fully-Qualified-Name) for the `MultipartBody` which is part of the `io.micronaut.http.client.*` API.

On the other hand, the `@Controller` endpoint should use the respective server type which is: `io.micronaut.http.server.multipart.MultipartBody`.
Note the FQN as well which is part of the `io.micronaut.http.server.*` API.

#### Client HTTP Headers

Under the hood, the generated *Micronaut* client will translate your `@Client` methods annotations to appropriate HTTP headers (the *Content-Type* HTTP header is the one of interest here). Those headers should obviously match your controller endpoint expected ones.

While the trivial approach would be to have the same endpoint annotation for the client and controller, this is unfortunately wrong: `@Client` and `@Controller` respective methods must have **reversed `produces` and `consumes`** annotation fields so that:

- the ***client produces** what the **controller consumes*** when sending the request then
- the ***client consumes** what the **controller produced*** when the response is received

#### MIME Types

In both your client and controller implementation, you are returning a `String`.
The endpoint annotation fields for content types specification should match the returned type which is `MediaTye.TEXT_PLAIN` for `java.lang.String` and not `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`

#### Fixed implementation

The `@Client` declarative interface then should look like below (with full `import`s, fixed input and result MIME types):

```java
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client;
import io.micronaut.http.client.multipart.MultipartBody;

@Client("http://localhost:8080/product")
public interface IHttpClient {
    @Post(consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, produces = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public String post(@Body MultipartBody file);
}
```

And here what the `@Controller` endpoint implementation would be (with appropriate `MultipartBody` and fixed result MIME type):

```java
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;
import io.micronaut.http.server.multipart.MultipartBody;

@Controller("/product")
public class ProductController implements IProductOperation {
    @Post(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String post(@Body MultipartBody file)  {
        return null;
    }
}
```